# How to disable angular-bootstrap-toggle

Tags: angular-bootstrap-toggle

I am using angular-bootstrap-toggle https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-bootstrap-toggle#demo
I am trying to find a way to put it in to a disable state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ng-disable to disable the toggle class from the [angular-bootstrap-toggle](https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-bootstrap-toggle), then you can check this [issue](https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-bootstrap-toggle/issues/4).

Other wise there exist a more hackable way to do this, add ng-class="{disabled : your_condition_here}" in your toogle. Like the code below

```
<toggle ng-model="toggleValue" ng-change="changed()" ng-class="{disabled : true}"></toggle>
```

and add below to your css file

```
toggle.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  opacity: 0.65;
}
```

Comment: It did the job! Maybe it's a hack but still better than editing the library (like suggested in the Github discussion you linked to). In my case this hacky behavior is acceptable.